# Gridview on rowediting postback hides the Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback, datasource

This is a very strange behavior, I cannot figure out what causing it.
basically, I have an `aspx` page, where I have a `button`, and a `gridview`.

pressing a `button` will fetch data from db into a `datatable` which will be used as `datasource` for the `gridview`.

This `gridview` has `commandfield showeditbutton="true"`

once the `databind` is successful and `gridview` has some records, i press on `edit button`. the edit button has following code on `rowediting`

```
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

surprisingly, after pressing `edit button`, `girdview` becomes hidden.

And when i press the `button` again, it brings it back in edit mode. Strange behaviour, any idea?

**.aspx page**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        CssClass="info-button-flat" onclick="Button1_Click1" />
    <br /><br /><br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**.cs page**

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string aPara= null;
        aPara= aUser.ID;
        clsDataConduit aConn = new clsDataConduit();
        aDataTable = new DataTable();
        aConn.AddParameter("@aPara", aPara);
        aDataTable = aConn.Return_aDataTable("an_user_sproc");
        GridView1.DataSource = aDataTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `GridView1_RowEditing` you are not rebinding to any datasource. Just `GridView1.DataBind();` wouldn't work unless you set `GridView1.DataSource = SomeSource;`

**Possible solution:**

Move the databinding code to a method called `BindData()`:

```
public void BindData()
{
    string aPara = null;
    aPara = aUser.ID;
    clsDataConduit aConn = new clsDataConduit();
    aDataTable = new DataTable();
    aConn.AddParameter("@aPara", aPara);
    aDataTable = aConn.Return_aDataTable("an_user_sproc");
    GridView1.DataSource = aDataTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

And call this method from Button_Click():

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindData();
}
```

In the `GridView1_RowEditing` call this method:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
}
```

You have to handle `GridView1_RowUpdating` where you will update underlying datasource. Hope it helps!